# How add name in task manager to program

Tags: c++, windows-8.1, codeblocks, taskmanager

How can i add the name field in task manager (windows 8.1) to my program. I wanted to show a description in task manager. not just exe name. I able to found how to do that in visual studio. But i'm in codeblocks. I tried adding resources.rc and compiling program. but it just add decription in file properties window. not in task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below line into the resources.rc is the solution. Then **write description here**  appear in task manager instead of exe file name.

```
VALUE "FileDescription", "write description here"
```